# Can I use netgroup at an NIS Client (Redhat) to restrict access to it?

Tags: configuration, redhat, nis

Our company has a central NIS configuration that we are using to access our teams servers (Redhat)...

The current configuration allows all valid NIS authenticated users to connect to our servers. 
We cannot update or change something on the NIS Master Server... so...

Is there a way to use netgroups or some other configuration to allow our team members to authenticate using the NIS server but still restrict access to all other users?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to use netgroups or some other configuration to allow our team members to authenticate using the NIS server but still restrict access to all other users?

That is pretty much why netgroups exist.

The easiest solution to do what you want is to use the `compat` functionality of `nsswitch.conf`. This is documented -- briefly and poorly -- in `nsswitch.conf(5)`:

> **Interaction with +/- syntax (compat mode)**
>
> ...In
>   /etc/passwd you could have entries of the form +user or
>   +@netgroup (include the specified user from the NIS passwd
>   map),  -user or -@netgroup (exclude the specified user), and
>   + (include every user, except the excluded ones, from the NIS
>   passwd map).

In practical terms, this means that if your `nsswitch.conf` looks like this:

```
passwd: compat
```

And your `/etc/passwd` ends with a line like this:

```
+@myusers
```

Then only members of the `myusers` netgroup will be able to authenticate to the system.

You can accomplish something similar using the `pam_listfile` module in your PAM configuration and creating restrictions based on group (rather than *netgroup*) membership.  This is nice if you have groups and netgroups that you're trying to keep in sync (because now you can just use standard Unix groups).  [This document](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-deny-allow-linux-user-group-login.html) has an example of restricting logins to specific groups using `pam_listfile`.

Comment: I kind of have tried that... I have created the file **/etc/netgroup** where I have `TeamUsers:     (,username1,)` then updated the **/etc/passwd** adding a new line at the end of the file like `+@TeamUsers` and finally updated the **/ets/nssconfig** with `passwd: compat` intead of `passwd: files nis`. After that no user can access the system!!! Maybe there is something wrong in the way I defined the netgroup??

Comment: Just creating `/etc/netgroup` isn't going to get you anything.  The netgroups have to be defined in NIS.  If you don't control the NIS servers and you can't get the netgroups created for you you will need to use the PAM mechanism instead.

Comment: Thank you! We found a working solution using the pam_listfile module after all!